# OpenNLP - Is training still required for abbreviation even with abbreviation dictionary?

Tags: computational-linguistics, computer-science

I just used [`OpenNLP`](https://opennlp.apache.org/) for a small program where I was supposed to segment a paragraph into sentences.

Although I was able to complete the task after reading some documentation and going through their test cases, I couldn't help but notice that I still have to train for all the abbreviations (example Yahoo!), even when I created a custom abbreviation dictionary, passed it to `SentenceDetectorFactory` and used it to train `SentenceDetectorME`.

I am using similar approach as used in this [test case](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/opennlp/tags/opennlp-1.5.3-rc3/opennlp-tools/src/test/java/opennlp/tools/sentdetect/SentenceDetectorFactoryTest.java?view=markup).

I couldn't find this behaviour in their documentation nor I could find any explanation.

Is there something I am missing or is it required to train the model on abbreviations as well? If it is required to train the model on abbreviations then why specify them separately?

Edit: I am using version `1.5.3-rc3`.